# mongodb driver c# - reflection in filter expression

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to build a filter for a MongoDB Collection in c# with Reflection.

```
IQueryable<Notification> collQuery = collection.AsQueryable()
  .Where(entity =>
    entity.GetType().GetProperty(filterProp.Name).GetValue(entity) == filter.FilterValue);
```

but when I call

```
collQuery.ToList()
```

I receive

> {document}.GetType().GetProperty("SenderName").GetValue({document}) is not supported.

Am I doing something wrong or this approach cannot be followed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use reflection inside `IQueryable` expression, but you can use it to create expression manually. Use thid method:

```
public static Expression<Func<Notification, bool>> CreateWherExpression(
    string propertyName, string filterValue)
{
    var notificationType = typeof(Notification);
    var entity = Expression.Parameter(notificationType, "entity");
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(entity, propertyName),
        Expression.Constant(filterValue));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Notification, bool>>(body, entity);
}
```

Now it is possible to apply it like this:

```
var where = CreateWherExpression(filterProp.Name, filter.FilterValue);
IQueryable<Notification> collQuery = collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(where);
```